# Choose an option error- windows 10

Tags: windows-10

When I open my pc it's showing like
choose an option

1. continue
2. use a device
3. use another o/s
4. troubleshooter
5. turn off your pc

I tried all of them. But none are working.
I have also tried startup repair.
When I chose **start-up repair** it shows - `you need to sign in as an administrator to continue` but there aren't any administrator accounts on this pc.

Please help me to fix this

Comment: Add a screenshot of this message to your post.

Comment: Sounds like your master boot record is broken, you probably need a reinstall of the OS.